# How to reduce number of deferred emails SMTP SendGrid

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid to send out emails. My Django code for sending emails looks something like this

```
        client_message = EmailMessage(
            'Subject',
            'Message Content',
            'Name <support@domain.org>',
            [client_email],
            ['support@domain.org], 
        )
        client_message.content_subtype = "html"
        client_message.attach('MyFile.pdf', file, 'application/pdf')
        client_message.send(fail_silently=False)
```

I have the content_subtype as HTML so that I can do page breaks between paragraphs.

I am sending out 2 emails at a time and am sending a very low volume, < 100 / day. I just began sending emails. My emails are landing in Gmail spam inbox and not getting delivered at all into Yahoo / Comcast. I have already whitelisted my own domain's DNS using SendGrid.

What is best policy for my email content so get them delivered? I have heard

1. Removing all hyperlinks in my message
2. Putting a physical mailing address in the footer of the email
3. Putting the words "reply STOP to unsubscribe" in the email footer
4. Changing the content type of my email from HTML

It's important that I attach the files when sending the email. What else can I do to make sure my emails go through?

Comment: did you follow all sendgrid instructions for dkim and spf on your domain?

Comment: also is your domain something in a network known for spam?

Comment: @Srgn I have not followed dkim and spf. I don't understand your second question -- my domain.org is hosted on Wix.com and then I am using AWS to host my app on app.domain.org

Comment: where do you manage the dns for the domain?

Comment: Wix -- I copied in CName DNS settings from SendGrid into Wix

Answer (score 1):

I had just verified my domain a few hours before sending the ultimately deferred emails. I believe the answer is that my domain verification was still being processed, and my emails landed in the the recipients inbox 2 days later. For future people having this problem, if possible see if the problem fixes itself after a few days.

Litmus.com is also a fantastic resource to check your content and security settings.